# Product flavors in android not working

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I have been stuck on this for a day now. I created 2 flavors for my project and added them under the buildtype in android in build.gradle. I then created a res folder for both and changed the icons for each. When I run the project for any of the variants, it is showing the icon from the project.

My project structure in as follows

```
[project]
   [app]
      src
        main
            res
               mipmap
        flavor1
        flavor2
            res
               mipmap
```

and my build.gradle is

```
    productFlavors {

    flavor1 {
        applicationId "abc"
    }

    flavor2 {
        applicationId "abc"
    }

}

sourceSets {
    flavo1 {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor1/res']
    }

    flavor2 {
         res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor2/res']
    }
}
```

PS: nvm the naming

Comment: Share your build.gradle and also how your files/folders are structured

Comment: @W0rmH0le done. I added them

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but do you have icons for all flavors and all folders (xxhdpi, xxxhdpi, hdpi, etc)? Just asking because maybe, the icon for you specific device/resolution is missing and android is selecting default ones from "main" folder.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the icon from `main` and leave it only in `flavor1` and `flavor2` directories.

Also check the names of the flavors in the build.gradle, I think it should be `flavor1` instead of `flavo1` and `flavor2` instead of `staging`.

Another note, sourceSets definition is not required, standard `res` directories inside flavors' directories will be used automatically.

Comment: I wrote the naming just for the sake of it. Do I need to create a manifest for each of the flavors?

Comment: It just seems there is some inconsistency in naming... Manifest for each flavor is not required.